# How to set folder permission with + at the end?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I'm trying to mount a network shared device in a linux box. I get permission issue but it was mounted properly in another linux server. The only difference on the server it works has a `+` permission at the end. Can anyone explain what it is and how can i set the same permission on the linux it is failing?

### Folder permission on the working machine

```
drwxr-xr-x+   14 root   root          32 Jan 1 12:02 shared_folder

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: shared_folder
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

### Folder permission on the non-working machine

```
drwxr-xr-x   14 root   root          32 Jan 1 12:02 shared_folder

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: shared_folder
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

I tried below to modify the acl permission and it don't work.

```
setfacl -m mask:rwx /software
setfacl: /software: Operation not supported
```

Comment: The `+` is ACL (access control list) you need to add the `acl` option to `/etc/fstab`.  It is likely that you also need to set the right ACLs with `setacl` to get the right permission sets.  Can you give the `getfacl shared_folder` on the machine it is working?

Comment: ```getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: shared_folder
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: Please, could you edit the question instead?  It makes life easier for everyone since all information is in the same place.  Have you remounted the disk with `acl` enabled?

Comment: Just updated with getfacl output. Do i just run setacl /shared_folder?

Comment: You need to set it in `/etc/fstab`, given that the mount happens at boot time.  Although i do not see anything in those ACL options that would make any real difference.  Today most machines use `acl` as a default option.  Try to give more details: the type of filesystem, `tune2fs -l <device>`, `mount -v`.  Also, what exact permission issue you're suffering (what error message in what condition)?